# Pip installing setup.py in Kube Flow Pipeline Component

Tags: python, kubeflow

I have a pipeline component .yaml specification that looks something like this:

```
inputs:
- {name: Input File Path, type: String, description: 'Input file path'}
- {name: Max Partitions, type: Integer, description: 'Max number of clusters'}
- {name: Min Partitions, type: Integer, description: 'Min number of clusters'}
- {name: Network Partition Uuid, optional: true, type: String, description: 'network_partition_uuid if planning to split partition'}
- {name: Output File Path, type: String, description: 'Output file path of optimal partitions'}

implementation:
  container:
    image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/root-sanctuary-178203/vertex-ai-rapids-image/rapidsai-core:23.02-cuda11.5-base-ubuntu20.04-py3.10
    # command is a list of strings (command-line arguments).
    # The YAML language has two syntaxes for lists and you can use either of them.
    # Here we use the "flow syntax" - comma-separated strings inside square brackets.
    command: [
      network_analysis, 
      generate-partitions,
    ]
    args:
    - --input_file_path
    - {inputValue: Input File Path}
    - --output_file_path
    - {inputValue: Output File Path}
    - --max_partitions
    - {inputValue: Max Partitions}
    - --min_partitions
    - {inputValue: Min Partitions}
    - if:
        cond: {isPresent: Network Partition Uuid}
        then: [--network_partition_uuid, {inputValue: Network Partition Uuid}]
```

however, as you can see, it calls the pip package network_analysis, which requires the package to be installed in the container before it can be used. This components are subsequently composed into a pipeline and composed into an Intermediate representation as a .json file.

Subsequently, this .json file is pushed onto cloud storage and reference by pub sub when the endpoint to trigger is called.

How will I install these dependencies for this component in the container, and how will it work since the repository lives locally, and only the json representation of the file exists that possibly references this code?

One way I can think of is to create a custom docker image to be hosted on dockerhub, built with the current repository, and the rapids image. Would this be a solution?